# How can I make an account/tag sort of variable which stores my users input?

Tags: variables, discord.js

I would like to know how you can make a function that would make a tag/account in discord that will store information about the users participation in the server and/or see how much money they have in they're fake virtual bank. This is a command sort of like dank memer. What I have now looks like this:

```js
var cards = [];
var money = 0;
var buildings = [];

var account = [`${cards}`, `${money}`, `${buildings}`];

if(!message.author.account) {
        message.channel.send(`If you want to use MR. HONI CHAN, then start by doing \`gimme start\``);
    }
```

I want to have something like:

```js
if(!message.author.have.account) {
       message.channel.send(`If you want to use MR. HONI CHAN, then start by doing \`gimme start\``);
}
```

but that is not proper code. Another thing that I need to do is the **gimme start** command. Here is what I have now:

```js
if(message.content === 'gimme start') {
       
}
```

and that is it because I don't know how to create a variable when a certain function is ran.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to have a database for storage. Would recommend enmap or other similar databases. For temporary storage, you can use

```
const tempDb = Discord.Collection();
```

For downloading the module:

```
npm i enmap
```

Using the db:

```
const enmap = require('enmap');
const db = new enmap({
  name: "db",
  cloneLevel: "deep",
  fetchAll: true,
  autoFetch: true
});
db.set('foo', 'bar');
await db.get('foo'); // returns bar
db.delete('foo');
```

Comment: Installing the enmap is giving me a bunch of errors

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention, you must install better-sqlite3 as well. Use `npm i better-sqlite3`